# Why does this SQL query with a `where not in` clause not work as expected?

Tags: mysql

Here's the [SQL Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5oPihy8pysUfUGMPA9GNMC/0) for this question.

These are the input tables:

Student table:

| student_id | student_name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Daniel |
| 2 | Jade |
| 3 | Stella |
| 4 | Jonathan |
| 5 | Will |

Exam table:

| exam_id | student_id | score |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 1 | 70 |
| 10 | 2 | 80 |
| 10 | 3 | 90 |
| 20 | 1 | 80 |
| 30 | 1 | 70 |
| 30 | 3 | 80 |
| 30 | 4 | 90 |
| 40 | 1 | 60 |
| 40 | 2 | 70 |
| 40 | 4 | 80 |

I need to find "quiet" students. A quiet student is the one who took at least one exam and did not score the highest or the lowest score. I need to write a solution to report the students (student_id, student_name) who were quiet in **all** exams. Student who has never taken any exam should not be included in the result.

For context this is an interview prep question and I have already solved it by other means. I am specifically trying to understand why the below query does not work.

```sql
with student_scores as (
select student_id, student_name, 
rank() over (partition by exam_id order by score asc) worse_rank,
rank() over (partition by exam_id order by score desc) best_rank

from Student
inner join Exam using (student_id)
)

select distinct student_id, student_name
from student_scores
where student_id not in (

select student_id
from student_scores
where ((worse_rank=1) or (best_rank=1)) and (student_id is not null)
)
```

However, this returns no record whereas I am expecting the record for student_id 2, Jade.

Some things I found while debugging:

1. It works if I use another CTE like so:

```sql
loud as (
  select distinct student_id
  from student_scores
  where ((worse_rank=1) or (best_rank=1)) and (student_id is not null)
)
```

and then use

```
where student_id not in (select student_id from loud)
```

but this only works if I use **distinct** in the extra CTE!

2. It works if I create the input tables by explicitly defining `student_id` as the PRIMARY KEY.
3. It also works if I use `student_name` in the `where not in` clause instead of `student_id`.
4. Adding distinct to the subquery after the `where not in` clause does not help.

Comment: code as published produces 1 row for jade in my local installation version '8.0.12' but no rows when run on dbfiddle.uk version 8.0.30 https://dbfiddle.uk/eKFnoxPP or your fiddle which is also 8.0.30

Comment: Weirdly of you change the or to union not in behaves as expected https://dbfiddle.uk/m46_6x-x

Comment: Thanks for checking on a different version of SQL. Yes, I noticed that if there was only one condition in the `not in` clause it worked as expected. It also seemed to be giving the expected result (but not the answer needed for this question) if I replace the `or` with `and`. I have no clue what's happening—it might just be something broke in this version.

Answer (score 0):

I would use an aggregation approach here, with the help of the `RANK()` window function:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY exam_id ORDER BY score) rnk1,
              RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY exam_id ORDER BY score DESC) rnk2
    FROM Exam
)

SELECT s.student_id, s.student_name
FROM Student s
INNER JOIN cte t
    ON t.student_id = s.student_id
GROUP BY s.student_id, s.student_name
HAVING SUM(t.rnk1 = 1) = 0 AND SUM(t.rnk2 = 1) = 0;
```

The `HAVING` clause asserts that any matching student was never the lowest or highest scorer on any exam.

Comment: Thanks but like I said, I have already solved it using other means and am "specifically trying to understand why the below query does not work".

Comment: I have no idea why your current query does not work, but note that your `WHERE` clause has a parentheses problem.  It should be: `WHERE (worse_rank = 1 OR best_rank = 1) AND student_id IS NOT NULL`

Comment: Thanks, that's fair; it doesn't change the outcome but I'll change it in the question to avoid confusion.